# How to configure Phalcon in the Nginx config file

Tags: php, configuration, nginx, phalcon

I am trying to set up an NGINx server to work with Phalcon PHP Framework.
So far I've been looking for help on the internet but I could not find anything...

My conf file is:

```
server {
#listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
#listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

root /usr/share/nginx/www;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name localhost;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to index.html
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}

location /doc/ {
    alias /usr/share/doc/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
}
```

What should add to it in order to make Phalcon work?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> I faced the same problem and finally got this working here is my configuration file using
>   Windows 7 and PHP 5.3 in Fast CGI mode.

```
server {
            listen      80;
            server_name localhost;
            set         $root_path 'C:/devtools/phalcon/test/public';
            root        $root_path;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
        location @rewrite {
                            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
                          }

        location ~ \.php {
         try_files    $uri =404;

        fastcgi_index  /index.php;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9123; #default is 9000, i am using 9123 
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
        root $root_path;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```